# S3 upload and access-How to monitor the direct upload of files from client to s3 from server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS.
I am learning upload a file from client directly to s3.Here are the steps

1. Client-1 sends request for file upload.
2. Server generates pre-signed url,keys etc and sends it to client-1.
3. Client-1 uploads the files directly to s3 using the keys it received from server.

- Now how can server (application) know that upload was successful?
- How can server access s3 content (Just like it accesses database content-like how many files are there,etc)?
- If client-2 wants to access a file uploaded by client-1,how server can
  programmatically give access to client-2 ? (Like expiring
  tokens,signed URLs.. Like how Facebook uses a long url with access keys for images,etc)

Thank you for answering!

Comment: After upload is done client1 can notify the server with the details of file which is uploaded. Once information is received the server can generate temporary url and access for client 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 can be configured to trigger an AWS Lambda function when a new object is created. It will provide the name of the bucket and object. However, there won't be a clear correlation between the client and the upload unless the pre-signed URL enforces a particular filename.

The server can then access the object in Amazon S3 via normal API calls, just like any other object stored in S3.

If client-2 wants to access the object, and the object is private, the server can generate a pre-signed URL to give client-2 access to the object.

See: [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)